# Make an element hit testable without border

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

Is it possible to have an element HitTestVisible without it showing a (blue) border around the element when the mouse enters the element?

Comment: What element you talking about?

Comment: A RichTextBox in this case. I do not want it user-editable (I've got that part, but I also don't want the "focus" of the element when you mouse over it, nor do I want the cursor to change), but I do want the user to be able to scroll through the textbox when the text overflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override **`ControlTemplate`** of RichTextBox to remove that feature.

```
<RichTextBox Cursor="Arrow">
    <RichTextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxBase">
            <Border
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    Name="border"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    Name="PART_ContentHost"
                    Focusable="False" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Opacity"
                            TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FF569DE5</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RichTextBox.Template>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Do you also happen to know how I can prevent it from changing the cursor?

Comment: Just set `Cursor="Arrow"` on your instance of RichTextBox. I have update the answer.

Comment: Aha, don't know how I didn't know that property existed. Thanks!